Bash / SED: Greedy vs Non Greedy
Hey I need help with regex
sed -i "" 's/\(.*\)\( @[^@]*\)/path:*\1*\2/' "$OUTPUT_LOCATION"

This will turn this
/Tests/UnitTests/ViewControllers/Test.UnitTest.swift @team1
/Tests/UnitTests/Auth.UnitTest.swift @team2
/Modules/Stuff/ @team1 @team2

into
path:*/Tests/UnitTests/ViewControllers/Test.UnitTest.swift* @team1
path:*/Tests/UnitTests/Auth.UnitTest.swift* @team1
path:*/Modules/Stuff/ @team1* @team2

But if you notice the last line the * is at the wrong place before the two teams responsible for /Modules/Stuff/? how do I modify the regex to look for the first @?

sed doesn't have non-greedy quantifiers.

Change .* to [^@]*?

Why wasn't that obvious? You did the same thing in the second group.

I've had help with regex since I'm not good with them. So I've been learning them as I go but reading it is a little difficult.

To nit pick, sed doesn't have greedy quantifiers either. Instead, the longest match wins. For example, echo 'fig123312apple' | sed -E 's/g[1-3]+(12apple)?/X/' gives fiX and echo 'fig123312apple' | perl -pe 's/g[1-3]+(12apple)?/X/' gives fiXapple
